# registration in node.js using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I got **User is not defined error** with this code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/api/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please fill all fields!'});
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name : req.body.name,
            email : req.body.email,
            password : req.body.password
        });
        // create the user
        newUser.addUser(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
            }
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
        });
    }
});
```

Then this is my user model aka user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('customers', new Schema({
  name : {
        type: String
    },
    email : {
        type : String
    },
    password : {
        type : String
    }
}));

// Add user
module.exports.addUser = function(user, callback){
    User.create(user, callback);
}
```

Anything wrong with my logic? I'm stuck for hours for this. I can see something when I do `console.log(User)` but when I try to create an instance it says it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I can see that's wrong with your logic, but the exports in your user model seem wrong.

First you set your entire module.exports object to the mongoose model:

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('customers', UserSchema);
```

which would be imported like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```

Which is just as you did.

But then you write over that, by exporting the addUser function/key.  The User model is no longer exported at all.  So in fact all you can really do with your module as it stands is:

```
var userStuff = require('../models/user');
userStuff.create(...);
```

As for how to fix it, you have many choices.  The minimal change is probably something like this:

```
var User = module.exports.User = mongoose.model('customers', UserSchema);
```

And then import it like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user').User;
```

Comment: addUser is just a function, what it has to do with my User?

Comment: You're overwriting your export. User is never exported.

Comment: I don't think so, addUser is just merely a method that I can use if I include user model. Hmm maybe the `new User` instance is unnecessary, because in my model there is alrdy a new schema, what do you think?